# How to run javascript Regular Expression in Mirth

Tags: javascript, regex, mirth

I have a the following string:

```
Source: "HKID:A1234567~PKey:00888880~DOC:TKWC033330"

Regex:  .*(HKID:.*?)(.+?)((?=~)|\s|\z)
```

When I test this at the JavaScript Regular Expression Test [site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) I got A1234567 so all are good.

I put this expression in a javascript transformer in my Mirth channel.  But the hk_id value i get back is either null or empty string.

Things I've tried:

1. use the function `re.match()` but this gives me error, mirth says
   `cannot find function match in object...`
2. I tried to put single quote around the regular expression below, or the `/`
3. I tried to reduce my regular expression to a simplest form to test which is `re.exec('.*')` and yet I still get the empty or null value.
4. Instead of running `RegExp.$1`, I tried return m only, but no differences were made.

I think it may boil down to how I escape the characters, but I can't find any Mirth document about this, if you have any insight they will be greatly appreciated.

```
var hk_id = Find_HKID();
var xml_msg = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <XML><Barcode="'+hk_id+'" /></XML>';

var sResp = ResponseFactory.getSuccessResponse(xml_msg)
responseMap.put('Response', sResp);


function Find_HKID() 
{
   var test = 'HKID:A1234567~PKey:00888880~DOC:TKWC033330'
   var re = new RegExp(test);
   var m = re.exec('.*(HKID:.*?)(.+?)((?=~)|\s|\z)');
   return RegExp.$1 + RegExp.$2 + RegExp.$3 + "";
}
```

Comment: you pass the regex string to `new Regex()`, not the string you're testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confused regex and and test string, it should be:

```
function Find_HKID() 
{
   var test = 'HKID:A1234567~PKey:00888880~DOC:TKWC033330'
   var re = new RegExp('.*(HKID:.*?)(.+?)((?=~)|\s|\z)');
   var m = re.exec(test);
   return RegExp.$1 + RegExp.$2 + RegExp.$3 + "";
}
```

[Now it works like a charm:-D](http://jsfiddle.net/MfENC/)

And btw. you should not use `new RegExp()`, it's slow and ugly. Use the regex directly:

```
var re = /.*(HKID:.*?)(.+?)((?=~)|\s|\z)/;
```

Edit: like Ωmega proposed this regex might work for you too, and is much more precise:

```
var re = /.*(HKID:.*?)[~\s]/
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel like I need a slap on the head lol, thank you very much.

Comment: @Fylix a case for [rubber duck debugging;)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: @Ωmega I think i put it this way because my test string not always the case, basically the regex does the following: get the value A1234567 when I have a ~ or it may have a space right after it or it may have nothing after it... hence the \s|\z i put in... I'm very new to regex so you are right I may have complicated it more then I should have.

Comment: Omega, you proposed a nice regex, but failed to solve the problem, that's all. No reason to rage downvote. That's live on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I see that problem is in question, not in answer... Undownvoting. And removing my answer as well.

Comment: @Ωmega Thank you, I edited my answer to give you credit. I just looked for the problem, not how the regex could be enhanced;)

Comment: @Ωmega while I thank you for your assistant, I think it is unfair to down vote my question because as per Christoph comment and also in my question; I got the result I want from my RegEx, my real question is how do i make it works with Mirth.  I did not ask how i can write up the RegEx to parse A1234567

Comment: @Fylix don't worry, sometimes there are people around that take this "game" too serious. I think my UV compensates for that;) Take a look at the regex I mentioned in the edit, it might work for you too.

Comment: @Christoph + Fylix :: I removed my downvote and I removed my answer by which I lost 10 points - not fair enough?